# mysqldump increases SQL server process memory footprint

Tags: mariadb, mysqldump, memory

i mentioned my initial problem here in this question (config is still the same):
[mariaDB with a 3 node galera cluster is eating more and more RAM](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/299306/mariadb-with-a-3-node-galera-cluster-is-eating-more-and-more-ram)

Now I have narrowed the problem down. I found out, that on the problematic node in this cluster there is a mysqldump backup job running. Whenever this mysqldump is running, the memory footprint of the mariadbd is growing.
That alone would not be the problem, but it is indeed growing beyond the configured limits in its config file! This particular node has 15G of RAM and after a few days with several dumps, the mariadbd process eats >95% of ram and the machine starts swapping.

So far I could not solve the problem, I tested several options I found in the net (--quick, --single-transaction), nothing helps.

Do the experts have any advice on this?
Thanks!

edit: I have upgraded to 10.5.11 in the meantime because I hoped, that problem was solved. It was not :/

Comment: What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  (Better yet, let's see all the variables and status:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning )

Comment: Pls check the link above to my original post, the config has not changed since then. Only the mariadb version has, because I was thinking of a memory leak etc.

Comment: OK, I provided that analysis there.  Suggest you file a bug report with MariaDB.  Meanwhile, periodically restarting that one node may prevent swapping.  The Cluster should gracefully recover from that brief outage.  (Or it might even go unnoticed!)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am doing so far, only good thing for now is, that I now know why this is happening :)

Comment: And post a link to the bug -- for other readers of this page.

Comment: It is already a known bug, but not yet marked as happening with 10.5.11
https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-19287

Comment: "SQL Server" is a competing product.  Please change the title _or_ explain why it is relevant.